# GitHub action fails: cannot find 'fulfillment' in scope

Tags: swift, xcode, github-actions, xctest

When running a GitHub action to test a macOS app, I get the following error:

```bash
error: cannot find 'fulfillment' in scope
```

As a matter of fact, I am using [XCTest's `fulfillment`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xctestcase/4109476-fulfillment/), that was introduced with Xcode 11.0+ and has the following availability:

```swift
@available(macOS 10.15, iOS 13.0, tvOS 13.0, watchOS 6.0, *)
```

So I am not sure why I get the error given that:

- My package is available for iOS 13 and beyond;
- The [software included](https://github.com/actions/runner-images/blob/macOS-12/20230709.1/images/macos/macos-12-Readme.md) in the GitHub runner image includes Xcode 14.

Any help to figure out how to fix this issue is welcome

Comment: Sometimes the version of Xcode in the list doesn't match reality on all instances. Try adding a step to run `xcodebuild -version` to confirm.

Comment: Same issue here with `xcodebuild -version` output `Xcode 14.2
Build version 14C18 `.

Comment: Reproduced on `macos-12` and `macos-13` runners

Comment: @Mick F do you use `swift-actions/setup-swift` ? I do to setup Swift 5.8.

Comment: As a workaround, using `xcodebuild` command seems to work.

Comment: Thanks @PierreMardon for your suggestions. I found the error: my Package.swift was declaring support for the macOS platform like so `.macOS(.v10_12)`. Changing it to `.macOS(.v10_15)` fixed the issue ‍♂️

Comment: Good for you @MickF!
No real clue of what's going on for me. Using `.macOS(.v12)`, I guess it really has to do with using `swift` CLI and `setup-swift` action, but I definitely would expect all of this to work out of the box.

Comment: @PierreMardon If your code is public, let me know, I would be happy to help.

Comment: @MickF it is! Here is my first trial and the next commits on the same PR were my attempts to solve it, leading to `xcodebuild` use.
Action : https://github.com/PittsCraft/SwiftRetrier/actions/runs/5638308502/job/15272302158

Related commit :
https://github.com/PittsCraft/SwiftRetrier/pull/1/commits/057b3f583188ef7797a7547e1bb61988542dcd52

Comment: @PierreMardon Back to square 1. I spoke too soon about fixing the issue: I made another mistake that ignored the error and made the action pass ‍♂️ — I gave your repo a try but couldn't fix it either. ‍♂️

Comment: OK, now it's good. Issue and workaround: https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-xctest/issues/436#issuecomment-1703589930